# Is this calculation of the expectation of Brownian motion correct?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider the two Brownian motions $W(t_{1})$ and $W(t_{2})$ with $(t_{2}\geq t_{1})$. We are interested in the following process:

$\mathbb{E}[e^{W(t_{2})-W(t_{1})}]$

We know $W(t_{2})-W(t_{1})$ is distributed as $N(0,t_{2}-t_{1})$ can we hence rewrite this expectation as:

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }xe^{{\sqrt{t_{2}-t_{1}}}x}f(x)dx$

(where  is the density of a standard normal random variable)?

Comment: No $x$ on the outside, otherwise it's right. (The method here is called the law of the unconscious statistician.)

Comment: You mean no x multiplying the exponent?

Comment: No, the $x$ outside the exponent is wrong. The $x$ inside the exponent is correct.

Comment: ah, so should be $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{{\sqrt{t_{2}-t_{1}}}x}f(x)dx$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: ah right, thanks!